# How to avoid table splitting last rows of table in next page with header in pdf

Tags: c#, pdf, itext7

i used itext7 for pdf generation code,i have created a table in itext7
I added a header cell so the header is displayed on every page.
i have a footer row which i added as cell to show GST and subtotal because I want this in last page only. problem is ,If the data is large then my footer
is broken in two pages and the header is also coming in last page, it looks weird.i want my last 2 footer rows always together.and if last 2 rows is only shown in last page dont show the header on this page.How i can achieve this.

This is my code

```
         using (System.IO.MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
         {
            var writer = new PdfWriter(stream);
            var pdf = new PdfDocument(writer);

            Document document = new Document(pdf, PageSize.A4,false);
            document.SetMargins(30, 30, 10, 30);                
            Paragraph header = new Paragraph("abcd")
            .SetTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER)
            .SetFontSize(13).SetBold();
            document.Add(header);           

            PdfFont fontNormal = 
            PdfFontFactory.CreateFont(StandardFonts.COURIER);

            PdfFont f_cbr = 
            PdfFontFactory.CreateFont(@"Utils\Fonts\CALIBRI.TTF");
            PdfFont f_cbrb = 
           PdfFontFactory.CreateFont(@Utils\Fonts\CALIBRIB.TTF");

            var company = _invoiceService.GetCompanyDetail(compId);
            var invoice=_invoiceService.GetInvoicesByCompany(compId.ToString());    

       string userName =  
       _invoiceService.GetUserbyId(long.Parse(CurrentUser.UserId));
       
         Table table = new Table(UnitValue.CreatePercentArray(new 
         float[] { 0.75F, 6.5F, 1.9F, 2.4F }))                      
        .SetFontSize(12).SetFont(f_cbr).UseAllAvailableWidth()
        .SetMarginBottom(30).SetMarginLeft(30)
        .SetMarginRight(30);
                           
            table.AddHeaderCell(new Cell(3, 2).Add(new Paragraph("Customer,").SetMarginLeft(5)).Add(new Paragraph().SetMarginLeft(5)).Add(new Paragraph().SetMarginLeft(5)).SetTextAlignment(TextAlignment.LEFT));

            table.AddHeaderCell(new Cell(1, 2).Add(new Paragraph("CompName").SetFontSize(14).Add(new Paragraph("mmmmmmm").SetFontSize(10)).SetTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER)));

            table.AddHeaderCell(new Cell(1, 1).Add(new Paragraph("Email").SetMarginRight(5)).Add(new Paragraph("Phone").SetMarginRight(5)).SetTextAlignment(TextAlignment.RIGHT).SetFontSize(11));

            table.AddHeaderCell(new Cell(1, 1).Add(new Paragraph().SetMarginLeft(5)).Add(new Paragraph("+88 88888 88888").SetMarginLeft(5)).SetTextAlignment(TextAlignment.LEFT).SetFontSize(11));

            table.AddHeaderCell(new Cell(1, 1).Add(new Paragraph("CIN").SetFontSize(11).SetMarginRight(5).SetTextAlignment(TextAlignment.RIGHT)));
            table.AddHeaderCell(new Cell(1, 1).Add(new Paragraph("123456789012345678901").SetFontSize(11).SetMarginLeft(5)));

            table.AddHeaderCell(new Cell(1, 2).SetFont(f_cbr).Add(new Paragraph("Your Order Details:").SetMarginLeft(5).SetTextAlignment(TextAlignment.LEFT)));                        //table.AddCell(new Cell(1, 1).Add(new Paragraph("Sl. # ")));
            table.AddHeaderCell(new Cell(1, 1).SetFontSize(11).SetFont(f_cbr).Add(new Paragraph("Invoice #").SetMarginRight(5)).Add(new Paragraph("Inv. Date").SetMarginRight(5)).SetTextAlignment(TextAlignment.RIGHT));

            table.AddHeaderCell(new Cell(1, 1).SetFontSize(11).Add(new Paragraph("IN0009-89001").SetMarginLeft(5)).Add(new Paragraph("03-Feb-2022").SetMarginLeft(5)).SetTextAlignment(TextAlignment.LEFT));
            
            table.AddHeaderCell(new Cell(1, 1).SetFont(f_cbr).Add(new Paragraph("Sl. # ").SetMarginLeft(5).SetBold()));
            table.AddHeaderCell(new Cell(1, 1).SetFont(f_cbr).Add(new Paragraph("Description ").SetMarginLeft(5).SetBold()));
            table.AddHeaderCell(new Cell(1, 1).SetFont(f_cbr).Add(new Paragraph("SAC Code ").SetMarginLeft(5).SetBold()));
            table.AddHeaderCell(new Cell(1, 1).SetFont(f_cbr).Add(new Paragraph("Amount(`)").SetMarginRight(5).SetBold().SetTextAlignment(TextAlignment.RIGHT)));
            
            DataTable tbl = new DataTable();
            tbl = GetTable();
            int c = 1;
            int subTotal = 0;
            int SGST = 0;
            int CGST = 0;
            int CESS = 0;
            int grantTotal = 0;
            int h = table.GetNumberOfRows();
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            {
                foreach (DataRow drItem in tbl.Rows)
                {                        
                    table.AddCell(new Cell(1, 1).SetFont(fontNormal).SetBorder(Border.NO_BORDER).SetBorderLeft(new SolidBorder(0)).Add(new Paragraph(c.ToString()+".").SetMarginLeft(5)));
                    table.AddCell(new Cell(1, 1).SetFont(fontNormal).SetBorder(Border.NO_BORDER).SetBorderLeft(new SolidBorder(0)).Add(new Paragraph( drItem["Description"].ToString()).SetMarginLeft(5)));                       
                    table.AddCell(new Cell(1, 1).SetFont(fontNormal).SetBorder(Border.NO_BORDER).SetBorderLeft(new SolidBorder(0)).Add(new Paragraph(drItem["SACCode"].ToString()).SetMarginLeft(5))).SetBorderBottom(new SolidBorder(0)).SetBorderRight(new SolidBorder(0));
                    table.AddCell(new Cell(1, 1).SetFont(fontNormal).SetBorder(Border.NO_BORDER).SetBorderLeft(new SolidBorder(0)).Add(new Paragraph(String.Format("{0:n}", drItem["Amount"])).SetMarginRight(5)).SetTextAlignment(TextAlignment.RIGHT));

                    subTotal = subTotal + (int)drItem["Amount"];
                    c++;
                }
               
            }
            //table.CreateRendererSubTree
            SGST = (subTotal / 100) * 9;
            CGST = (subTotal / 100) * 9;
            CESS = (subTotal / 100) * 1;
            grantTotal = (subTotal + SGST + CGST + CESS);

           

            table.AddCell(new Cell(3, 2).Add(new Paragraph("Rupees,").SetFont(f_cbr).SetFontSize(11).SetMarginLeft(5)).Add(new Paragraph("One thousand one hundred ninety only.").SetMarginLeft(5)).SetTextAlignment(TextAlignment.LEFT));
            table.AddCell(new Cell(1, 1).Add(new Paragraph("Sub Total").SetMarginRight(5).SetTextAlignment(TextAlignment.RIGHT)));
            table.AddCell(new Cell(1, 1).Add(new Paragraph(String.Format("{0:n}", subTotal)).SetMarginRight(5).SetTextAlignment(TextAlignment.RIGHT)));
            table.AddCell(new Cell(1, 1).Add(new Paragraph("SGST @ 9%").SetMarginRight(5).SetTextAlignment(TextAlignment.RIGHT).SetFontColor(ColorConstants.RED)));
            table.AddCell(new Cell(1, 1).Add(new Paragraph(String.Format("{0:n}", SGST)).SetMarginRight(5).SetTextAlignment(TextAlignment.RIGHT).SetFontColor(ColorConstants.RED)));
            table.AddCell(new Cell(1, 1).Add(new Paragraph("CGST @ 9%").SetMarginRight(5).SetTextAlignment(TextAlignment.RIGHT).SetFontColor(ColorConstants.RED)));
            table.AddCell(new Cell(1, 1).Add(new Paragraph(String.Format("{0:n}", CGST)).SetTextAlignment(TextAlignment.RIGHT).SetMarginRight(5)).SetFontColor(ColorConstants.RED));

            table.AddCell(new Cell(2, 2).SetFont(f_cbr).SetFontSize(11).Add(new Paragraph("Transfer to,").SetMarginLeft(5)).Add(new Paragraph("Ms. ABCD Systems | A/c #: 8888888888888888").SetMarginLeft(5)).Add(new Paragraph("EFGHIUVW Bank | xyz Br. | IFSC: SIBL0000371").SetMarginLeft(5)).SetTextAlignment(TextAlignment.LEFT));

            table.AddCell(new Cell(1, 1).Add(new Paragraph("CESS @ 1%").SetMarginRight(5).SetTextAlignment(TextAlignment.RIGHT)).SetFontColor(ColorConstants.RED));
            table.AddCell(new Cell(1, 1).Add(new Paragraph(String.Format("{0:n}", CESS)).SetTextAlignment(TextAlignment.RIGHT).SetMarginRight(5)).SetFontColor(ColorConstants.RED));
            table.AddCell(new Cell(1, 1).Add(new Paragraph("Grand Total").SetMarginRight(5).SetTextAlignment(TextAlignment.RIGHT)));
            table.AddCell(new Cell(1, 1).Add(new Paragraph(String.Format("{0:n}", grantTotal)).SetMarginRight(5).SetTextAlignment(TextAlignment.RIGHT)));

            document.Add(table);                
            document.Close();
            writer.Close();
            stream.Close();
            byte[] bytes = stream.ToArray();
           
            return File(bytes,System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Pdf, "test");

        }
```

Comment: sharing the code could help the community to help you

Comment: In iText 7, there is a method to keep the contents of the row together using  cell.setKeepTogether(keepFirstCellTogether).  The setKeepTogether() method is defined at the BlockElement level so you can use it with Paragraph, Div and Cell object of Table. Please refer an example of setKeepTogether on iText KB https://kb.itextpdf.com/home/it7kb/examples/rowspan-and-splitting

Comment: i want to show from rupees cell to last cell always on same page and also if it goes to  next page it should not show header columns.